# Resolve same domain name with different virtual directory to different VM / IP

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, nginx, dns, virtual-machine

I have two VMs running, both have a public IP address, and I have a domain name, say www.example.com. What I want to achieve is,

- Resolve www.example.com/project1 to VM1's IP
- Resolve www.example.com/project2 to VM2's IP

Is that possible? If so how can I do it? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [proxy a url using mod\_rewrite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103931/proxy-a-url-using-mod-rewrite)

Comment: No, they are actually different questions. In the question linked, there are two domains but one server. I have two VMs but want to use one domain with different path / virtual directory.

Comment: The difference is miniscule. They have one rule, you'd have two. The solution is the same for both.

Comment: But I don't have another domain to rewrite to. I only have one domain and two IP addresses.

Comment: So use the IP address instead of a domain in the substitution.